# Everything Up to Date but really isn't github

Tags: github

I git cloned a repo down to my local machine.
I forked that repo to my github account.
I made changes in my local files in sublime
I removed the original repo's origin because I want to push to my now forked repo
and then continue to alter my local files

when I do `git diff` you see the files I altered
when I do `git remote -v` I successfully see my forked repo

when I do `git push -u origin master` I get Everything is up to date but it isn't ...

and when I do `git branch` I am in my master branch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `git commit`, then `push` the new commit to your remote repository.

`git diff` compares the files on disk to what git is tracking; `git push` compares what git is tracking locally to the remote.